# Django - how to notify the user that form was submitted successfully or not?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I created a small form where the user can enter his name and upload a text file. Now, after the user clicks on upload, I want to display a message on the screen like a toast or something that will say whether the upload was successful or not. I'm not quit sure how to do it, because after, submitting the form, the user just get redirected to another page.

**Side note: I use Django 1.7 (I know it's old, but this is the project I got to work on from someone else)**

Here is my html snippet where the user fills the fields:

```
<form action="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}upload/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" placeholder="Name" style="width:100%">
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], str(request.FILES['file']), name)
    return HttpResponse("Successful")


def handle_uploaded_file(file, filename, name):

    # if not os.path.exists('upload/'):
    #     os.mkdir('upload/')
    fileContent = ""
    with open('upload/' + filename, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            fileContent += chunk
            # destination.write(chunk)

    currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()

    policy = Policy.create(name, currentDT, fileContent);
    policy.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/)

You will just have to

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Form submitted successfully.')
```

And in your template

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message  }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

But don't forget to set things up in the MIDDLEWARE and Storage backends

Comment: Thanks, so this approach will prevent the redirection that happens when I do: return HttpResponse("Successful") ?

Comment: yes, and it's much simpler as django does everything for you ;)

Comment: I still do need to return something from my upload function, don't I? I tried this and got " The view policies.views.upload didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. "

Comment: Yes, the way it works is, it store your message and it display it in the next page your user end up to. So you should redirect at the end of your validation.

Comment: I see, is there a way I can show the message as a pop up or a toast, and not as a list?

Comment: Yes, you still it as you wish. But keep in mind, that there could be more than one message at a time. The messages stack until there are display once